# Access control exercise - java

Tags: java

I need to print the attributes from TestCar class by creating a public hackCar method in class Terminal. The hackCar method needs to take a TestCar as a parameter and print the attributes of TestCar. The caveat for this assignment is that I cannot touch anything in the TestCar class.

I am still struggling with printing the two private attributes in TestCar. How can I print the two private attributes from Test Car class by using the Test Car object as the parameter in the hackCar method?

Story class:

```
class Story {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TestCar testCar = new TestCar();
        Terminal terminal = new Terminal();
        terminal.hackCar(testCar);
    }
}
```

class Terminal {

```
 public void hackCar(TestCar other) {

        System.out.println(other.doorUnlockCode);

        System.out.println(other.hasAirCondition);

        System.out.println(other.brand);

        System.out.println(other.licensePlate);
}
```

}

```
class TestCar {

    private int doorUnlockCode = 602413;
    protected boolean hasAirCondition = false;
    String brand = "TurboCarCompany";
    public String licensePlate = "PHP-600";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: So what is the actual question here?

Comment: What makes you think that fields always need a getter and a setter method?! And yes: this is not a "homework assessment" service. Please ask a clear, specific question. "Review my stuff please" isn't...

Comment: Strictly speaking a getter method in a class without any fields doesn't make sense either. Are you sure those methods do not belong in your `TestCar` class? Doing so would allow you to call `other.hasAirCondition()` in your Terminal's `hackCar(...)` method

Comment: Apologies all for not being more specific. I am new to programming and this community so appreciate your patience. I need to print the attributes from the TestCar class by implementing the hackCar method and using Test Car as a parameter. The TestCar class is restricted for the sake of the assignment so they don't belong there.

Answer (score 1):

Private fields are called 'private' because there is no way to get them. But you can  make public getter for them:

```
class TestCar {
    // Your 4 fields here...

    public int getDoorUnlockCode() {
        return this.doorUnlockCode;
    }
}
```

Then in `hackCar` method change
`System.out.println(other.doorUnlockCode);` to this: `System.out.println(other.getDoorUnlockCode());`
So now you can access field `doorUnlockCode` through public getter.

Do the same for protected field `hasAirCondition`

Your methods `Terminal.getdoorUnlockCode()` and `Terminal.getAirCondition()` can't get to fields from another object, they must be in `TestCar` object

Comment: Thanks alaster, I should have noted that TestCar class is restricted so I cannot alter the access modifier for these variables.